# What architectural model is commonly used in large, enterprise, functional F# development?

Tags: architecture, f#, functional-programming

I've been using F# in scripting (data science work) and developing class libraries to use with C#. In the latter case, I've been creating modules with pure functional code.

If I wanted to start developing large applications entirely in F#, I'm not sure how I'd structure it. I find the functional style of development very intuitive, but can it scale to large enterprise applications? Is it more common to, say, use an OO structure and then flesh out the objects using functional code?

Intuitively, it feels like writing lots of functions without some kind of class structure could get unwieldy. But I'm perfectly willing to accept that might just be down to years of "brainwashing" from working on OO projects.

Presumably there must be Haskell enterprise applications that are entirely functional, so maybe this is also true in F#. Or maybe it's a lot of pain to do *everything* functionally, so F# devs mix and match. I don't know.

Can anyone point me at articles that discuss how to scale up the functional paradigm to large enterprise application development?

Comment: @Sylwester as it stands; NO. It's currently a combination polling-external resource request. It needs some rephrasing before migration is viable.

Comment: @Sylwester That and it has [a dupe](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/167134/25768)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is cover by an existing question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/167134

Comment: @user3018144 A bad experience in a company doesn't automatically makes F# suck for everyone and C# is certainly not less bug prone than F#

Comment: Perhaps you'll find my Pluralsight course [A Functional Architecture with F#](http://bitly.com/functionalarchitecturewithfsharp) interesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer to the question, but I think there is a lot you can learn from some of the large community projects in F#. They might not be large enterprise software, but they are fairly large if you count all the F# dependencies they use.

I think that well-designed functional libraries can be extremely composable and this is an approach that works overall quite well for the community.

- I did a talk about [the F# open source community](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/6153-the-big-f-and-open-source-love-story) at the F# eXchange (the second part is more interesting), [the slides are here](http://tpetricek.github.io/Talks/2015/love-open-source/london/#/).
- I [talked about library design](http://tpetricek.github.io/Talks/2015/functional-libraries/paris/#/) (slides) at NCRAFTS in Paris
- I wrote two articles on this topic - one is about [multiple levels of abstraction](http://tomasp.net/blog/2015/library-layers/) and one is about [libraries vs. frameworks](http://tomasp.net/blog/2015/library-frameworks/).

All of this focuses more on components (libraries) than complete applications, but I think the complete application can very well be just s thin layer combining multiple composable components together.

Comment: Do you happen to know any large enterprise app built entirely in F#?

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa: [Tachyus approach](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8545278) is one example of successful building of enterprise upon pure F#.  Another one is [Jet.com](http://jet.com) where the backend of large e-commerce system is almost 100% F#-implemented.